# Trying to serve prepacked JavaScript GZipped files

Tags: jetty, mime-types, embedded-jetty

I have gzipped file bundle.js.gz on my Jetty embedded server.

I have added correct Mime type and encoding, but I am still getting

*bundle.js.gz:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL error in Chrome.*

This is how I add the encoding to to the handler:

```
MimeTypes mimeTypes = externalWebApp.getMimeTypes();
mimeTypes.addMimeMapping("gz", "text/javascript; gzip");
```

This takes change, I can see Content-Type: *text/javascript; gzip* in Chrome Dev tools.

I try to include the resource like this:

```
<script src="/dist/bundle.js.gz" /></script>
```

Any suggestions?